# Should I have one event listener that updates all sprites, or should each sprite have its own event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

So, I'm making a game. The way I currently have it, is, each sprite-type has one "gameloop" event listener, and that "gameloop" event does all the game logic for each one in a for loop, for example:

```
    document.addEventListener("gameLoop", function () {
       for (var l = 0; l < sprites.length; l++) {
          (function () {
            var sprite = sprites[l]
              //game logic for each sprite here.
            }
           })()
       }
    }, false)
```

I can have around 40 or so of these sprites at any given point in my game. I would assume that this method would be much more optimize than having EACH sprite have its own event listener, like so:

```
for (var l = 0; l < sprites.length; l++) {
  (function () {
    var sprite = sprites[l]
    sprite.element.addEventListener("gameLoop", function () {
            //game logic for each sprite here.
          }
    }, false)
  })()
}
```

I'd also like to mention that these sprites are constantly being created and deleted, so I'm not sure how eventlisteners work, and if their corresponding elements get deleted, they also get deleted, I'd hope so, otherwise, I would think that this approach definitely wouldn't work.

Comment: One event updates N elements is definitely more efficient than N events updates N elements.

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought! thanks for the confirmation!